# How to catch multiple HTTP requests in one connection in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, http

I have an embedded system that sends some data to my webserver.
I am making HTTP GET requests to my web server that runs Apache 2.4.12 and PHP 5.4.40.

A piece of PHP code is managing the GET request and putting the values to the database.

Here is how my raw GET request from the embedded side look like, it is currently HTTP 1.1 with keep-alive option enabled by default but I have tried HTTP 1.0, too:

```
GET /add.php?sensor=001&id=000000000&temp=+00.0&hum=00.0&td=00:00:00-00.00.2000 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.25\r\n\r\n
```

Whenever I am making a GET request to my web server and disconnecting the socket from embedded side, it perfectly works and does what I need. However, I do not want to disconnect and re-handshake and re-connect each time since I have lots of data to send.

However, if I do not disconnect the socket after making the request to my web server, it only works for the first request in the *request group* that it creates.

Wireshark is showing the request detail as, for example: "HTTP request 11/127". So, as I guess, these multiple GET requests are grouped in items of 18, 116, 127, 135 etc.. However, only the first request in the group get processed and others are ignored. Also, an HTTP 400 Bad Request is generated by the server as well as HTTP 200 OK, at the same time.

How do I handle the other items in the group?

Comment: use http-keepalives?

Comment: @MarcB I am already keeping the connection alive and that is probably what is causing the problem..

Comment: U are keeping it alive ok. Is the 2nd packet sent 9 hours later

Comment: @DrewPierce No, the second message is sent in milliseconds.. I have noted that I have tried with HTTP 1.0, too. It is sent in a very fast manner that even HTTP 1.0 didn't kill the connection.